# JAVA HttpsConnection POST send image and text

Tags: java, image, post, http-status-code-400, telegram-bot

I am trying to send a text and a image via HTTP POST and I always get a 400 error. I would like to use it to send a image via Telegram bot and I am using the code provided in this answer with a text and bite parameters https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/1970613 with small modifications.

What could be the error ?

````java
String param  = "chat_id=mi_id&photo=";
String charset = "UTF-8"; 
String request = "https://api.telegram.org/bot-botCOde/sendPhoto";
URL url = new URL( request );
File binaryFile = new File("/home/joseantonio/imagen.jpg");
String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.
String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());

HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setUseCaches( false );
try { 
    OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);

    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param\"").append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
    writer.append(CRLF).append(param).append(CRLF).flush();
                         
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"binaryFile\"; filename=\"" + binaryFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Type: image/jpg").append(CRLF);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
    writer.append(CRLF).flush();                             
    Files.copy(binaryFile.toPath(), output);
    output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
    writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of boundary.

    // End of multipart/form-data.
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF).flush();

    int responseCode2 = conn.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + request);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode2);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fact that you are using https url is the cause of the error you are getting. You need to handle things a little different when you are submitting to an https url.  See an example [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077600/learn-java/java-tip-96--use-https-in-your-java-client-code.html)